# Unable to pass command line arguments in Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, windows

I just installed Ruby 2.0.0 on Windows 7 (using "rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p247-x64.exe"). I think the File associations are OK:

```
$> assoc .rb
.rb = rbfile

$> ftype rbfile
rbfile="C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\ruby.exe" "%1" %*
```

However, I cannot pass any arguments to the interpreter.

So if I run a simple script (test.rb):

```
puts ARGV[0]
```

it gives nothing:

```
>test.rb test1
>
```

I guess I should add that I had Ruby 1.9.3 installed till yesterday. I  uninstalled it, and installed the above (Ruby 2.0.0). Everything used to work fine in Ruby 1.9.3.

Please help !!

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you repeating the assoc? you have `.rb` and `rbfile` twice

Comment: Sorry, that was my first time posting a question, and I didn't know how to format it correctly. I've corrected it now.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Hello_world#Windows ?

Comment: Yes, .rb scripts are recognized, and work fine (e.g. "puts hello" outputs "hello"), but command line arguments are not passed. The assoc and ftype show the correct thing, as mentioned above.

Comment: I know this is not really different, but for a lack of a better answer, check: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Simple_Ruby_Examples#Associating%5FRuby%5FFiles%5Fon%5FWindows

Comment: Are you running those commands as an administrator?

Comment: Have you tried to run the ruby file by the `command` ruby ?

Comment: @screenmutt I have tried both ways

Comment: @code4j the ruby file runs fine, it just doesn't recognize arguments

Comment: @user2566225 I have tested the code on Mac with ruby 2.0.0 installed on rvm. And it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other people had [similar problems](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rubyinstaller/ARGV%7Csort%3adate/rubyinstaller/JJS0CJcLujw/YkBqp3B6zQEJ) with Vista and Ruby 1.9 in the past.  It seemed to be related to manual modifications or broken uninstalls of old versions.

A clean install of "rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p247-x64.exe" on Windows 7 works for me.  The `assoc` and `ftype` commands do *not* know about ruby.

```
> assoc .rb
File association not found for extension .rb

> ftype rbfile
File type 'rbfile' not found or no open command associated with it.
```

I'd suggest you unset these values by starting a Shell as Administrator and running `ftype rbfile=` and `assoc .rb=`.  If this doesn't help (make a backup and) delete all registry keys containing `rbfile`.  The correct keys use `RubyFile` or `RubyWFile`.  The [InnoSetup Script](https://raw.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/master/resources/installer/rubyinstaller.iss) contains the correct registry entries.

Comment: I unset the ftype rbfile and assoc .rb values, did a clean install of the 32-bit version, reset the assoc .rb and ftype rbfile associations, and it worked ! So I'm going to stick to that for now.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me in Windows 7:

- Run regedit
- Find HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\ruby.exe\shell\open\command
- Make sure the "(default)" entry says:
  (Default)  REG_SZ "C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\ruby.exe" "%1" %*
  When I checked, the %* was missing in mine.
  Of course, the ruby path must match where your ruby is installed.